# Detecting and joining series of line segments that run along each other

Tags: algorithm, geometry, mapkit, line, computational-geometry

Given: Several circular series of map GPS coordinates for several bus routes. The GPS coordinates are not all equal when they run along the same road. The number of GPS coordinates for a single bus route runs from 140-600.

Problem: When the points are downloaded drawn, the raw routes don't follow each other perfectly and especially when zoomed-out you can't see some of the routes. I want to somehow show the multiple routes that run along a road, mostly likely dashed with multiple colors. But in order to do that, I need to detect the segments of the route that run really close to each other.

What would be perfect is finding the segments of the routes and mutating their GPS coords to be shared among them. Once that's done I can easily render it.

So my question is: are there any good algorithms for this purpose, or some combination/tweaks of other algorithms I can use? It all has to be done autonomously in an app, not hand-done/hand-checked.

If you need any other information please ask.

There's one idea where using the routes as polygons, I can check to see if the polygons intersect, but is there a way to see if only the edges slightly intersect, and return which points along the complicated route have that slight intersection?

[image: 5 Routes: 3 one one side of the road overlapping, 2 on the other overlapping.] 5 Routes: 3 one one side of the road overlapping, 2 on the other overlapping.

Comment: This is more of an idea/question than an answer: The bus service in a city is usually between fixed bus stations and bus stops. If they are represented as nodes in a graph (and available bus roots as edges, if you have that info), I think this problem will become a lot simpler and most importantly more robust.  Then once you have your GPS data, all you have to do is find our which nodes of the graph they connect —if node<Central> is connected to node<CityCentre> by one set of GPS data already,  you can use that information to filter out corresponding *edges* from another set of GPS data.